# Shutdown of Azure VMs sometimes hangs for minutes

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine, shutdown

Inside an Azure Pipeline we used the Azure Resource Group Deployment Task with the Shutdown Action as well as the Stop-AzureVM cmdlet to shutdown an Azure VM for some managing activities.

Usually the shutdown finishes in a few seconds. But sometime we had to wait for several minutes (today around 10 mins).

Is there any trick to ensure a fast shutdown?

Comment: did you alread use the `- force` option of `Stop-AzureVM`?

Answer (score 0):

While not a direct answer to your question - I usually use ARM Rest API, query to it is almost instantaneous and it is async, so as long as you get 202 you dont care what happens next, it will get shutdown eventually. That allows me to shutdown\startup about 100 entities.

Code for this is rather long, but general idea is something like this:

```
$token = (Get-AzureRmContext).TokenCache.ReadItems() | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty AccessToken
$header = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $token" }
Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $header -Method Post -Uri $uri -UseBasicParsing
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately from my experience there is no trick to ensure a fast "graceful' shutdown of a VM.  Sometimes it takes longer because of the service and processes running on said machine.

**Keep in mind that this is not an Azure or a VM thing, its more of an OS think.**